# Транскрипция фонетическая

Tags: транскрипция

математика [мът`и(с призвуком э)мАт`ькъ]
психология [п`с`и(с призвуком э)х^лОг`иja]

Comment: Гласные звуки И,Ы,У - не редуцируются. Звуки О, А четко слышатся только по ударением.

Answer (score 1):

математика - [мът'и(э)мАт'икъ]; психология - [пс'и(э)х^лОг`иjь]